# What allows a team to pick 4 bans?

Tags: league-of-legends

During the banning phase of a ranked game, the enemy team was able to ban 4 champs and we were only able to ban 2. What would have caused this?
[image]

Comment: This is a glitch. Your team was still able to make three bans, but one of them shows up as an enemy ban instead.

Comment: this is probably caused by high latency, because the showing of banned champions is executed locally, but the banning is executed on the server. if now the ban arrives at your PC before your PC processed the "older" ban, it will be shown as an enemy ban

Comment: @Vogel612 my latency rarely goes above 100

Comment: Still more than likely a glitch or the servers were having problems.

Comment: @Paralytic mine too, but sometimes i have inexplicable communication issues with the server, which could with high probability cause these problems, but this would only occur on high server useage

Comment: This is lag.  You both banned 3 champs one of them just showed up on the other side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no mode that lets a team ban more than 3 champions.

The screenshot you provided does not make any sense, since even if there were 4 bans per team, the left team should have 3 bans, seeing as how bans alternate between the two teams. It is most likely a client-side bug.